# How to get Chrome fullscreen with selenoid vnc

Tags: selenoid

I'm having trouble seeing a fullscreen browser when using VNC with selenoid.

[image]

I'm running in docker on a linux vagrant VM. I'm using the default commands to start the containers...

```
docker run --rm -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v ${HOME}:/root -e OVERRIDE_HOME=${HOME} aerokube/cm:latest-release selenoid start --vnc --tmpfs 128

docker run -d --name selenoid-ui --link selenoid -p 8080:8080 aerokube/selenoid-ui --selenoid-uri=http://selenoid:4444
```

This is my C# code that initializes the remote webdriver...

```
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddArguments("--start-maximized");
chromeOptions.AddArguments("--disable-extensions");

var desiredCapabilities = chromeOptions.ToCapabilities() as DesiredCapabilities;
desiredCapabilities.Platform = new Platform(PlatformType.Any);
desiredCapabilities.SetCapability("enableVNC", true);

_currentWebDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), desiredCapabilities);
```

What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because in current images we have no window manager. As a workaround you can set window size explicitly.

```
driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1920, 1080));
```

Currently we are working on fixing this issue. The following [PR](https://github.com/aerokube/selenoid-images/pull/30) adds Fluxbox window manager. We hope to rebuild all images during next weeks.